# NAS starts to slow for mounting via fstab

Tags: mount, cifs

To save energy, the NAS is shut down at night, and is started again by the first booting computer via WakeOnLan. After that, shares should be mounted by the computer.

Unfortunately, the NAS is taking to long to boot and making the shares available, which results in the shares not being mounted. After a reboot of the computer, the shares are mounted successfully.

This is my entry in fstab:

```
//192.168.178.22/share  /mnt/nas  cifs  noauto,_netdev,credentials=/path/to/credentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,uid=thomas,gid=users,x-systemd.automount  0  0
```

Is there an option missing? Do some options clash and result in a mounting on startup only? What else can it be?

Comment: Some options to consider: 1. can you set the NAS to start up on a timer instead of a WoL packet? if so, maybe set it to power on about 10 minutes before the expected time it will be needed (e.g. 8:50am for a 9am start).  2. manually power on the NAS before any workstations.  3. can the NAS hibernate instead of completely shut-down? That should boot up faster.

Comment: Use automount instead of static fstab.